# Throttling and Bulking calls to a service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I am using spring webflux to create an aggregation service that acts as an aggregator/facade and calls other service and collect the results then sends them as an aggregate DTO.

To prevent overloading the APIs with query calls I would like to consolidate calls per API endpoint. All incoming requests for each individual API should be kept in a queue and be forwarded to the API as soon as a cap of 3 calls for an individual API is reached.

Is there a solution using spring or this needs to be done using basic data structures like a queue?